# Stuck in Qt Designer - hooking up buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to create a phone dialer using python and Iam using QT Designer to do it.

I have laid out a simple UI and I have also exported the code of the .ui file to python code (see code here: https://pastebin.com/bPYjnU0k
).

The issue I am having is I cannot figure out how to get the "phone number" to display in the QLineEdit when the buttons are pressed on the keypad.
Here is a code snippet of my code showing the button dialogs (again: full code at pastebin in the link above):

```
def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton_numZero.setText(_translate("Dialog", "0", None))
        self.pushButton_num4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "4", None))
        self.pushButton_num3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "3", None))
        self.pushButton_num5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "5", None))
        self.pushButton_num6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "6", None))
        self.pushButton_num1.setText(_translate("Dialog", "1", None))
        self.pushButton_num9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "9", None))
        self.pushButton_num2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2", None))
        self.pushButton_num7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "7", None))
        self.pushButton_num8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "8", None))
        self.pushButton_numStar.setText(_translate("Dialog", "*", None))
        self.pushButton_numPound.setText(_translate("Dialog", "#", None))
        self.pushButton_del.setText(_translate("Dialog", "DEL", None))
        self.pushButton_call.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Call", None))
        self.number_display.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "Dial Number ...", None))
        self.pushButton_Contacts.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Plp", None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I hook the dial pad buttons up to make the "phone number" display when I press the buttons to "dial" the phone number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PyQt points out in [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) it is not recommended to modify the file generated by Qt Designer, so I will assume that this file is called ui_dialog.py. Going to the problem, you must connect the clicked signal of each button and according to the button, implement the logic of adding or deleting text, etc.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_dialog import Ui_Dialog

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        buttons = (
            self.pushButton_num1, self.pushButton_num2, self.pushButton_num3, 
            self.pushButton_num4, self.pushButton_num5, self.pushButton_num6, 
            self.pushButton_num7, self.pushButton_num8, self.pushButton_num9,
            self.pushButton_numStar, self.pushButton_numZero, self.pushButton_numPound,
            self.pushButton_call, self.pushButton_del, self.pushButton_Contacts)
        for btn in buttons:
            btn.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        current_text = self.number_display.text()
        t = self.sender().text()
        if t in ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "*", "#"):
            self.number_display.setText(current_text + t)
        elif t == "DEL":
            self.number_display.setText(current_text[:-1])
        elif t == "Call":
            print("Call to: "+ current_text)
        elif t == "Plp":
            print("Plp")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```